# checking for one type returned by functions in an object

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
type GetMethod<T> = () => Promise<T[]>
type GetItemMethod<T> = () => Promise<T>

interface Methods<T = unknown> {
  getMethod: GetMethod<T>;
  getItemMethod?: GetItemMethod<T>;
}
```

And there is a function that takes this interface as an argument, for type checking I return the argument

```
type CheckTypes<Options extends Methods> =
  Options['getMethod'] extends Function
    ? ValuesType<Awaited<ReturnType<Options['getMethod']>>>
    : unknown

function testFn<Options extends Methods>(props: Methods<CheckTypes<Options>>): CheckTypes<Options> {
  return props
}

type Fn1 = () => Promise<{ test: 1 }>
type Fn2 = () => Promise<{ test: 2 }[]>
const fn1: Fn1 = () => {}
const fn2: Fn2 = () => {}

const fData = testFn({
  getItemMethod: fn1,
  getMethod: fn2,
})
```

With such a notation, or even if only the "getMethod" method is left, the return type will always be "unknown", how can types be rewritten so that all methods have the same return type

Comment: When I paste your code into a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wkk92W), I get many errors - all of which are irrelevant to the problem. If you could provide a minimal example that can reproduce the issue you are facing, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Could you please resolve [the remaining errors](https://tsplay.dev/NVb67N)? That would help your code become a [mre], as recommended by [ask].  It's also not clear to me what the problem is or what you're trying to do.  A well-defined code-based use case would be very helpful.  What type do you *want* to see for `fData`?